# How to declare a enum parameter for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which has several kind of parameters, INT, VARCHAR, DateTime, etc... This sp inserts a record into a log table with the parameters passed in. There are differents log tables, three exactly, which are called for example, LogTbl1, LogTbl2 and LogTbl3. This sp writes to LogTbl1, LogTbl2 or LogTbl3 depending on a sp parameter that indicates where to write to. I have set this parameter as tinyint and this takes as values 0, 1 or 2. Then depending on the value passed in, I build a dynamic query to write to the appropiate Log Table as below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTraceLog] 
    @LogId int, 
    @param2 int,
    @param3 int,
    @param4 varchar(100),
    @DateSent datetime,
    @TargetTable tinyint = 0
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @tblName nvarchar(100)

    SET @tblName = CASE @TargetTable 
                     WHEN 0 THEN '[dbo].[LogTbl1]'
                     WHEN 1 THEN '[dbo].[LogTbl2]'
                     WHEN 2 THEN '[dbo].[LogTbl3]'
                     ELSE ''
                  END

    IF @tblName <> ''
    BEGIN
      SET @sqlCommand =
        'INSERT INTO ' + @tblName +
                   '([LogId]' +
                   ',[param2]' +
                   ',[param3]' +
                   ',[param4]' +
                   ',[Date]) ' +
             'VALUES' +
                   '(@LogId' +
                   ',@param2' +
                   ',@param3' +
                   ',@param4' +               
                   ',@DateSent)'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
    END
END
```

So is there any other better elegant way to do it? Not possible using an enumeration in the sp parameter @TargetTable?

Comment: Try to declare TargetTable variable as table variable: declare @TargetTable (target tinyint) and pass an array of values to procedure.

Comment: @JohnMaxwell I would like something human readable rather than put numbers, 0, 1, 2...

Comment: You already know - there is no ENUM functionality in tsql. And "better" has no real measurement as it is relative to many factors. And if `@TargetTable` does not not have a valid value you should throw a useful error rather than ignore the attempt. Seems to me the bigger problem is the duplicate tables - a very different question.

Comment: I would write three more procedures. One for each of the tables to insert into. Then keep this as a "driver" procedure. Then you decide which other procedure to call instead of resorting to dynamic sql which will expose to possible sql injection.

Comment: I'd also add, that maybe you should have one log table, with a new field indicating the type of log record (i.e. what type goes into Log1 or Log2 or Log3).

Comment: It's not good SQL Server convention to prefix your Stored Procedures with "sp". That should be reserved for system SPs in the master database.

Comment: @HardCode, maybe but we want to separate logs coming from production, developement a test environment. This is the reason why we are separating them in different tables.

Comment: @Ralph then my point is that the new field in one log table would have one of the following values: Production | Development | Test. Then, for each record in the single log table, you know where that record came from.

Comment: @HardCode Finally I decided to separate stored procedure into 3 sps and avoid using dynamic sql query to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building up dynamic SQL then executing it means that Sql Server can't do a very good job of building an execution plan. This may impact efficiency and will matter most if the SP is called very frequently, which it looks like this SP will be.

Although the code would be less elegant I think it would be more efficient if your code had an `if @TargetTable` statement which contained three separate inserts which are all identical except for the table name you're inserting into.

But that doesn't answer the question. There is no enum and I don't think there is a problem with the type you've used to identify the log you want to write to. If you want the code to be more readable you could split it into three SPs and call them `spTraceLog1`, `spTraceLog2` etc. and not pass in the TargetTable. I would avoid the dynamic SQL if possible.